# Decimal to String "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

```
private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select * FROM PRODUCTS where [PRODUCT CODE] = '" + comboBox4.Text + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            int decimPRICE = myReader.GetInt32(myReader.GetOrdinal("PRICE"));
            string PRICE = decimPRICE.ToString("0.00");
            textBox7.Text = PRICE;

        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exe.Message);
    }
}
```

Its in **ComboBox** to **Textbox**

This codes is ok, but  "**Specified cast is not valid**"  is appearing when i clicked **item/index** in **ComboBox**. I dont know why.

**decimPRICE** is PRICE (decimal 18,2).

Comment: No, according to your declaration decimPrice is an int,

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace, and indicate which line of your code it's referring to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you probably just want:

```
decimal price = reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("PRICE"));
textBox7.Text = price.ToString("0.00");
```

Basically, `decimal` and `int` aren't the same things, and if you're storing a value as a decimal, you almost certainly don't want to just lose everything after the decimal point.

Additionally, now we can see more of your code, you should stop doing this **immediately**:

```
// WARNING! WARNING! SQL INJECTION ATTACK!
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select * FROM PRODUCTS where [PRODUCT CODE] = '" + comboBox4.Text + "'", con);
```

This is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) - you should instead use parameterized SQL:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM PRODUCTS where [PRODUCT CODE] = @code, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = comboBox4.Text;
```

This should be the first thing you change - it's a *gaping* security hole at the moment.

You should *also* open the connection fresh each time, and have it (and the command, and the reader) in `using` statements so they are disposed appropriately.

Next, if there are multiple matching products you're only actually using the last result - is that what you want?

Next, you're only using the price - so why use `SELECT *`?

Finally, this looks like a WinForms GUI or similar - in which case you shouldn't do this in the UI thread. Any long-running work should be done in a separate thread, or using asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Perfectionist: See my edit - there's a *lot* more to improve in this code.

Comment: Oooh That's too much for a day, well ill gonna read it again. You just dont help me but you also teached me. i really appreciate it, SIR! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`GetDecimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdecimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
decimal decimPRICE = myReader.GetDecimal(myReader.GetOrdinal("PRICE"));
string PRICE = decimPRICE.ToString("0.00");
textBox7.Text = PRICE;
```

Note that `decimPRICE` is now `decimal` instead of `int`.

Your exception was raised because `GetInt32` can not cast a DB decimal into an `Int32`.

Comment: Just saw OP added more code... Jon Skeet discussed it sufficiently, so I won't repeat it.